# I want to move some code to inside of a component in react-native, but it will mess up the variable scopes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react-native application I am writing and I want to move some code to an inner component.  The problem is if I do this I can't figure out how to make it work because of variable scope.  Can someone please take a look?

I have tried moving the code and it doesn't work.  I don't know how to write clean code that does this.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
    import { type ImageHolder } from './ImageHolder'
    import OuterComponent from "./OuterComponent"

    const imageholder2: ImageHolder[] = [
      {
        id: "1",
        actualimage: require("./images/image1.jpeg"),
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        actualimage: require("./images/image2.jpg"),
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        actualimage: require("./images/image3.jpg"),
      },
      {
        id: "4",
        actualimage: require("./images/image4.jpg"),
      },
    ];


    //The following code works fine, but I want to move the code to a 
    //button that is inside of another component.  


    export default function App() {
      const [currentImageIndex, setCurrentImageIndex] = useState(0)

      return (
        <View>
          <View>
            {
                imageholder2[currentImageIndex] &&
                  <Image
                    key={imageholder2[currentImageIndex].id}
                    style = {{
                      width: 300,
                      height: 300,
                    }}
                    source={imageholder2[currentImageIndex].actualimage}
                  />
            }
          </View>
          <View>  /*this button code is what I want to move because my button will be inside another component8?*/
          <Button
              title= "Press me"
              onPress={() => setCurrentImageIndex(currentImageIndex == 
    imageholder2.length - 1 ?
                   0 :
                  currentImageIndex + 1
              )}
          />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }

    /*here is my component with the button, but I don't know how to make the button functionality work because of scope.*/

    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {
      Image, StyleSheet, View, Text,Dimensions, Button
    } from "react-native";
    import Animated from "react-native-reanimated";



    export default class OuterComponent extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <View style ={{
          backgroundColor: "#C0C0C0",
          flexDirection: 'row',
        }}>
        <Button
            title= "Press me"
            onPress={() => setCurrentImageIndex(currentImageIndex == 
    imageholder2.length - 1 ?
                0 :
                currentImageIndex + 1
            )}
        />
        </View>
      )
    }
    }

    /*so in my app.js file I should just be able to do
    <OuterComponent /> or something similar and it should work.
```

The app should simply cycle through the images when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get around variable scope issue by passing a callback function to your inner component and executing all scope specific code within the component that still requires it (in this case your images). It would look something like this:

```js
const scopeSpecificFunction =() => {
  ...
}

<ParentComponent>
  <ChildComponent callbackfunction={()=>scopeSpecificFunction()}>
    {...children}
  </ChildComponent>
<ParentComponent>

//--------------------
// then the child component (Button) in another file

export default ChildComponent(props)...

<View>
  <Button onPress={()=>props.callbackfunction()} />
</View>
```

I hope that helps and is clear enough. Call backs in general can circumvent inter component scoping issues.

Comment: Thanks @Stuart Gough!! I need to think about it and go through it a little before I can accept the answer, but it looks like the ticket!!

Comment: No worries. In your child component in the code that you posted you just need to make sure you are passing props and you should be golden. This article explains it perfectly 
https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17
All the best.

Comment: Happy to hear it! All the best.